# Allow specific users to see specific files - Django

Tags: django, django-models, abac

I'm building a system to manage documents using Django, so I want to allow specific users (based on their ID o email) to read specific documents (uploaded by the same user or shared with another one specified by the file creator).
How can I build this feature?

Comment: you could take a look at Django Group. you can set each user to a specific groups and set permission to read, write, update and so on.

Comment: So I will have N users and N groups.. I think it’s not optimized

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved by using Google Buckets: every user has a bucket on Google Storage and the database in django webapp stores relationship user/bucket/credentials for access.